# How to separate results from SQL with ODBC

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have a query that is returning results. The fields are, Category, Part Number, Description and list price.

So the results show like:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]

What I would like to do is separate my results based on the Category. I.E Every Change in Category.

So my results would look like

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|  Category   | Part Number | Description  |  Cost  |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
| Category B1 |             |              |        |
| B1          |        6200 | Tubing 1"    | $13.00 |
| B1          |        6201 | Tubing 1.75" | $14.00 |
| Category B2 |             |              |        |
| B2          |        6300 | Tubing 2"    | $16.00 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
```

I am pulling this into a PHP page from a SQL server using ODBC.

I get get the results but can not figure how to make a break in between sections and preferably be able to name them even if it is category name.

Comment: Can you include a minimal version of the code that generates the table you currently have?

Comment: Please provide what have you tried till now

Comment: I am pulling from a SQL server. I have a few fields but bon sure how best to do this. Right now I am utilizing two dropdowns. #1 being Main category and second one as sub category. This is our pricebook so tying to make it look clean for those not computer literate.